# Insert more than one record using GraphQL Mutation

Tags: graphql

I would like to insert more than one record using GraphQL Mutation but it is giving error. here is the code which I have used to perform this.

```
input BusinessImageInput {
  business_id: Int
  image_url: String
}

mutation MyMutation($images: [BusinessImageInput!]) {
  insert_business_images(objects: [$images]) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

And here is variable which i want to pass as paramter.

```
{"images":  [
    {
    "business_id": 15,
    "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTVzlb1cEw8E0LeLJzk9c0OQV-N387Nt2Kn5w&usqp=CAU"
    },
    {
       "business_id": 15,
       "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTVzlb1cEw8E0LeLJzk9c0OQV-N387Nt2Kn5w&usqp=CAU"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.query",
        "code": "bad-request"
      },
      "message": "not a valid GraphQL query"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is one glaring issue in your code. This line

```
insert_business_images(objects: [$images]) {
```

should be

```
insert_business_images(objects: $images) {
```

Notice the removed square brackets.

If that does not help, then we'll need more information, such as:

- what error do you get?
- which implementation of GraphQL are you using both client-side and server-side?
- what does the GraphQL code (and possibly resolvers) look like on the server? You have only given us the client-side of the equation.

Comment: I am using graphQL API Explorer. Attached error details in question details.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as

```
mutation MyMutation($images: [BusinessImageInput!]) {
  insert_business_images(images: $images) {
```

or

```
mutation MyMutation($objects: [BusinessImageInput!]) {
  insert_business_images(objects: $objects) {
```

depends on **server `insert_business_images` mutation definition**, the name of argument (`images` or `objects` ?) - use explorer ... and [as you can see above] usually input arg and variable are same-named, they only differs with `$` prefix.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Also **you must follow server input types**.